# Gloss animations jerky and hope to add `-O2` to GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, gloss

I am trying the [gloss](http://gloss.ouroborus.net/) package in Haskell and have been able to build and run some examples successfully on windows.

The problem is animations jerky.

From the gloss' official page:

> Q: Animations seem jerky.
>
> A: Make sure you're compiling with -O2 -threaded. Without the threaded runtime, the code that manages the frame rate will behave badly. This is because GHC takes too long to reschedule the gloss process after the sleep timer has expired. With the threaded runtime, most simple animations should run at about 100fps, which is our internal frame-rate cap.

Yeah. After adding the `ghc-options: -O2 -threaded` in my cabal file, the jerky was eliminated (when running the `.exe` file).

But how to eliminate the jerky in REPL?

I have tried

```
cabal repl
ghci> :set -threaded
ghci> :set -O2
when making flags consistent: warning:
    Optimization flags are incompatible with the byte-code interpreter; optimiza
tion flags ignored.
ghci> main
```

It doesn't work, i.e. the animation was still jerk.

It seems that the problem is not just `-threaded`, but involves `-O2`.

Is there way to workaround it.

GHC 9.6.3, Gloss 1.13.2.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Enabling -O2 with the bytecode interpreter

Since GHC 9.8 you can enable optimisations in GHCi:

> Before GHC 9.8, optimizations were considered too unstable to be used with the bytecode interpreter. This restriction has been lifted,
> but is still regarded as experimental and guarded by
> [`-funoptimized-core-for-interpreter`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/debugging.html#ghc-flag--funoptimized-core-for-interpreter), which is enabled by default. In order to use optimizations, run:
>
> ```
> ghci -fno-unoptimized-core-for-interpreter -O
> ```

https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.8.1/docs/users_guide/ghci.html#faq-and-things-to-watch-out-for

Although there is another warning in the documentation of that flag:

> It is not recommended for normal use and can cause a compiler panic.

### Using -fobject-code to avoid bytecode altogether

There is also another option if the above is not fast enough. You can use the option `-fobject-code` to compile the Haskell source files you load to native object code instead of bytecode. This is often faster (and can be combined with `-O2` even on older GHC versions), however some GHCi features will not work like breakpoints and viewing non-exported functions.

More info in the documentation here:

https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.8.1/docs/users_guide/ghci.html#compiling-to-object-code-inside-ghci

### Use --nonmoving-gc

On [the GHC issue you opened](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/24416), Matthew Pickering suggested that the cause might be garbage collector pauses, and that indeed is the case.

GHCi needs to carry around a lot of data to interpret your program, which causes the garbage collector to slow down significantly even for simple programs. The default garbage collector needs to stop the whole program each time it collects garbage and that introduces pauses.

There is an alternative "non-moving" garbage collector which does not cause such long pauses, but it has less throughput in general. In your case throughput is not that important compared to pause times, so you should use the non-moving GC. You can do that by setting the `--nonmoving-gc` RTS option:

```
cabal repl gloss-hello --repl-options="+RTS --nonmoving-gc -RTS"
```

This removes all stuttering for me with the `gloss-hello` example. For more intensive applications you might want to consider combining this with one of the above options.

Comment: After updating to  GHC 9.8.1, there is no complain for `:set -O2` in REPL now, but the animation is still jerky, i.e. `cabal repl`, `:set -fno-unoptimized-core-for-interpreter -O`, `:set -threaded`, `:set -O2` with no warning, but still jerky. P.S. running .exe is OK as before.

Comment: @chansey can you try `cabal repl --repl-options="-fno-unoptimized-core-for-interpreter -O2 -threaded"`? Maybe the `:set` options you use are only picked up after the library has already been loaded. Another possibility of course is that the bytecode interpreter is too slow even with optimized core. It still doesn't use native compilation after all.

Comment: Just tried `cabal repl --repl-options="-fno-unoptimized-core-for-interpreter -O2 -threaded"`, still jerky. Nonetheless, thanks for your reply. I will continue to wait for a while and then accept yours if no better answers.

Comment: @chansey I've now added another option to my answer which is to use `-fobject-code` (together with `-O2` and `-threaded`). Can you try that?

Comment: I tried `cabal repl --repl-options="-fobject-code -O2 -threaded"` and `cabal repl --repl-options="-fno-unoptimized-core-for-interpreter -O2 -fobject-code -threaded"`, no improvement (still jerky), I'm not sure if I was using it correctly though.

Comment: > Compiling to object code takes longer, but typically the code will execute 10-20 times faster than byte-code.

My project is not very large. It is just two files, Yampa.hs and Examples.hs from https://github.com/ivanperez-keera/yampa-gloss/tree/v0.2.1 . Other code are packages that installed by cabal. So I run the `cabal repl` is fast. The "compiling process" (I mean fobject-code) is not as slow as the documentation says.

Comment: @chansey I've now had the change to try it for myself. This had the much better performance than the default: `cabal repl gloss-boids --repl-options="-fno-ghci-sandbox -O -fobject-code -threaded"` but it is indeed still not on par with `cabal run` performance.

Comment: Yeah. For the gloss-boids example, your approach does significantly improve the performance! If just `cabal repl gloss-boids` the game would be very very slow (even freeze my window).

Comment: However, for the Yampa example (I mean yampa-examples-gloss-rotatingcolor in https://github.com/ivanperez-keera/yampa-gloss/tree/v0.2.1). The animation is still jerky (Note that the yampa-examples-gloss-rotatingcolor is a very small, compared to gloss-boids). In fact, gloss-boids has the same problem, if you carefully compare gloss-boids with `repl` and `run`, circles run very smoothly in the `run` version, but the `repl` version is jerky.  Another possibility is due to they were not using the delta time correctly, but I haven't explored that further.

Comment: @chansey You're right, even with the simple `gloss-hello` example there's clearly a difference in FPS between `repl` and `run` even though the repl should be plenty fast for that. If you want to get answers to why that is then I think the best option is to open an issue with GHC itself: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues

Comment: OK. I will create that, thanks.

Comment: I have registered gitlab.haskell.org, but need admin to approval.

Comment: @chansey you can speed up the process by asking around on the mailing list, Matrix, or IRC: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/contributing#getting-a-gitlab-account

Comment: Done. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/24416

Comment: @chansey I've added the solution discussed in that issue to my answer.

Comment: I tried your approach. Did you test under windows or linux? On my computer (win 7) it crashed, log messages, see https://pastecode.io/s/oqaz8dzr However, I believe your approach works, because rarely it can run, but much faster than before

Comment: Seems like there's still problems with the nonmoving GC. Time to open another issue... It seems similar to this one: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/23003, but that should have been fixed in GHC 9.8.1.

Comment: I did some tests. It doesn’t seem to require a large program to be able to reproduce. Just a small program (print "Hello world") can reproduce, but Main.hs must import some packages. I will create a new issue at GitLab (also this issue can be reproduced on Win10).

BTW, I have tried some gloss examples that doesn't crash (e.g.Zen, Clock, Machina), the result is that they are really fast, and no different from running .exe. I accept your great answer. Thanks.

Comment: Done: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/24443